# ngx-slick-carousel issues with Angular 8

Tags: angular8

I am using [ngx-slick-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-slick-carousel) in angular 8.2.14 and I am getting images in 2 lines during scroll

[image]

This is my **HTML** code:

```
<ngx-slick-carousel class="carousel" #slickModal="slick-carousel" [config]="slideConfig">
      <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="slide">
        <img src="{{ slide.img }}" alt="" width="100%">
      </div>
    </ngx-slick-carousel>
```

This is my **TS** code:

```
slides = [
    { img: "../../assets/xd5.jpg" },
    { img: "../../assets/xd5.jpg" },
    { img: "../../assets/xd5.jpg" },
    { img: "../../assets/xd5.jpg" },
    { img: "../../assets/xd5.jpg" },
    { img: "../../assets/xd5.jpg" }
  ];
  slideConfig = { "slidesToShow": 4, "slidesToScroll": 1, "autoplay": true, "centerMode": true };
```

Answer (score 0):

first you must be installed the slick-carousel with npm then add the line below into your
angular.json file into scrpits section

> "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js"

and then you must add the

> "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss",
>
> "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss"

files into css section.